# Rename file to a hidden file for loop

Tags: bash

I'm writing a fairly basic shell script that loops through files within a directory and renames the file and adds a dot(.) to the start of the file however it does not work

any insight on whats going wrong?

```
for file in /tmp/test/*; do
 mv $file \\.$file;
done
```

Comment: Does your `mv` command work outside the loop? What is the output if you change the `mv` command to `echo mv $file \\.$file;` ? What do your filenames look like? Please show the input data and the expected output filenames.

Comment: `$file` contains complete path and file name. You prefix complete path with a dot.

Comment: How do I just get the filename within the directory

Comment: `basename "$file"`. See: `man man` and `man basename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. You're putting the dot before the whole pathname, not just the filename part.
2. You're prefixing the filename with `\.` instead of just `.`. There's no need for `\\` in the `mv` command.

Corrected code:

```
for file in /tmp/test/*; do
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/.${file##*/}";
done
```

`${file%/*}` returns the value of `$file` with everything starting from the last `/` removed, which is the directory part of the pathname. `${file##*/}"` returns the value of `$file` with everything up to the last `/` removed, which is the filename part. Then it puts them back together with `/.` between them, which adds the `.` prefix that you want to the filename part. See [Bash parameter expansion documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for details of these operators.

Also, remember to quote variables so you don't get errors when the variable contains whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script that takes a directory argument:

hide_files.sh:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ ! -d $1 ]; then
    echo 'invalid dir arg.'
    exit 1
fi

for f in $(ls $1); do
    mv -v "$1/$f" "$1/.$f"
done
```

output:

```
$ bash hide_files.sh mydir
mydir/a -> mydir/.a
mydir/c -> mydir/.c
```